# Ruby on Rails redirect_to missing parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been doing some the last part of my assingment in Ruby on Rails and I'm stuck on redirect_to for an hour.

I want to achieve this kind of structure on the URI.

```
http://localhost:3000/movies?ratings[G]&ratings[R]
```

My current code on this:

```
redirect_to :controller => 'movies', :ratings => session[:ratings_uri]
#session[:ratings_uri] = "ratings[G]&ratings[R]"
```

And this is what I got after the redirection.

```
http://localhost:3000/movies?ratings=%26ratings[G]%26ratings[R]
```

My question is, Is there any way to make my desired URL? Do I need to delete some paramaters on my code.

Comment: Your `session[:ratings_uri]` has a bad smell, why not just store ratings as a array? But you can use something like `redirect_to movies_url(Hash[session[:ratings_uri].split('&').map {|k| [k, 1]}])`

Comment: Did you try setting an instance variable, such as `@ratings = session[:ratings_uri]` and referencing `@ratings` in your `erb`?

Comment: It works! Thanks! Gotta review your code!